# JQuery and SPServices Date Format

Tags: jquery, date, spservices

So I found some code where a guy is using JQuery function for formatting dates in SharePoint with SPServices. I am currently doing the same method but can't get it to work.

I would like to format the date from `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to `MMM-dd` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get it to work properly in my example on codepen.

Any help would be great http://codepen.io/deaconf19/pen/xGNgoJ?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to moment.js file. This can be downloaded from [here](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js).
And in java script use the format you want to display:

```js
var startDate = "2015-08-18 13:14:15";
alert(moment(startDate).format('MMM-DD'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```